# C++ qt control cursor position in console

Tags: c++, qt, console-application

I'm writing a Qt console application. I need functions to control cursor position in console(gnome-terminal)(move it back, forward, on the nex-previous line).

I have tried to seek this functions in QtCore, but unsuccessful. Does Qt have at all such tools?

Comment: as it've written in qt assistant: "This class is mainly used to create mouse cursors that are associated with particular widgets and to get and set the position of the mouse cursor."       i don't need to control  mouse cursor  , furthermore i don't want to use qt's widget.  i want console application, so i need in tool to control  text cursor position in console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, Qt does not have any functions for abstracting the console in such a manner.

You can probably use another library rather easily, as it is unlikely to interfere with Qt much.

Answer (score 0):

For Qt try this (It works for me, Qt 5.10, compiler: msvc2015):

```
#include <Windows.h>
...
int main()
{
 QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
...
HANDLE hConsole_c = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
COORD pos = {40, 20};
SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole_c,pos);
cout << "x";
...
return a.exec()
}
```